# Duplicate elements ID with pry to check for XPath - Appium | Android | Ruby -

Tags: android, ruby, xpath, pry

Basic question

I have Grid view and that have all elements duplicate  here is example of elements

android.widget.TextView (3)
  text: 00/00/2017
  id: com.boost:id/date_textview

In grid, I am seeing all time this value repeating again and again. I am using binary,pry ( pry in command line )

so when i do id('com.boost:id/date_textview') It will return first date which is 00/00/2017 now I need to xpath that's what I am trying to do

In command line, When I do id('com.boost:id/date_textview') that's works what will be command for xpath for similar out ? It should be something that will return me date when I pass xpath

Please let me know if anything  is not clear I will try to explain better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used find_elements function that return all value of that id mean if same id has been use 4 times and each time have different value  in this case find_elements will return 4 value in array and you can use that value easily.